# MotorEngine - How to represent the equivalent of the foreign key in model?

Tags: mongodb, tornado, motorengine

In MongoDB I have a document that represents a Balance which has an Stakeholder's ID as a field.

I need to relate these two classes, Balance and Stakeholder, but I don't know what's the proper way. I've seen there's a field that could be appropiate but I still don't understand it: [EmbeddedDocumentField()](https://motorengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling.html#embedding-vs-referencing)

```
class Balance(Document):
    id = UUIDField()
    creation_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_on_insert=True)
    gross_balance = FloatField(required=True, min_value=0, default=0)
    balances_description = StringField(required=True, max_length=255)
    stake_holder = #FK to Stakeholder

class Stakeholder(Document):
    ...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Stakeholder represents document from other collection and `stake_holder` is ObjectId, you should use [ReferenceField()](https://motorengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling.html#motorengine.fields.reference_field.ReferenceField)

`stake_holder = ReferenceField(reference_document_type=Stakeholder)`